# Local and global constraints for fuzzy regex pattern matching

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching, fuzzy-search

The fantastic [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library in `python` allows for fuzzy pattern matching based on insertion, deletion and substitution costs and thresholds. For example

```py
>>> import regex as re
>>> m = re.search('(larry){e<=2}', 'starry', re.BESTMATCH)
>>> m
<regex.Match object; span=(1, 6), match='tarry', fuzzy_counts=(1, 0, 0)>
>>> # 1 sub, 0 ins, 0 del
>>> m.fuzzy_changes
([1], [], [])
>>> # subs at positions 1, no ins, no del in text
```

shows that the *pattern* `'larry'` matches the *text* `'starry'` as `'tarry'` with a single substitution at position `1` in the *text* conforming to the constraint `{e<=2}`. Similarly,

```py
>>> m = re.search('(larry){e<=2}', 'arrs', re.BESTMATCH)
>>> m
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='arrs', fuzzy_counts=(1, 0, 1)>
>>> m.fuzzy_changes
([3], [], [0])
```

matches `'larry'` as `'arrs'` after a single substitution and deletion at the beginning and end of the *text*.

My question is, can we write the regex pattern in such a way that certain operations are not allowed at certain parts of the matching process? For example, could we rewrite the pattern to allow insertions and deletions everywhere, except at the first and last matched characters which must be an exact match or a substitution, while limiting the overall number of insertion, substitution and deletion within the complete match via the cost equation?

Based on the second example, I would want to do the matching in such a way that there is no deletion of the first or last character of the pattern in the text matching. I tried the following, and it kinda worked. But I am not sure if this is foolproof.

```py
>>> m = re.search('((l){s<=1}(arr){e<=3}(y){s<=1}){e<=3}', 'arrs', re.BESTMATCH)
>>> m
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='arrs', fuzzy_counts=(2, 0, 1)>
>>> m.fuzzy_changes
([0, 3], [], [1])
```

I was trying to make the engine understand that (1) there can be at most three errors of any type in the overall pattern when being matched to the text, but (2) for the first and last characters those errors must be substitutions if at all required, while the remaining errors maybe in the middle of the pattern. Is the formulation correct? Is there a general way of writing the pattern to limit certain operations in certain sub-regions, while constraining the overall pattern globally?